# java Regex - ignore quotes?

Tags: java, regex

I want to catch a single quoted text , however escaped single quote (\') shouldn't be considered a delimiter,
for example:

> This 'wasn\'t the best' day

shall return

> - wasn't the best

Thanks.

I've tried this:

```
    public static List<String> cropQuoted (String s) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\'[^']*\\'");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    ArrayList found = new ArrayList();
    while(m.find()){
        found.add(m.group().replaceAll("\'", ""));
        System.out.println(m.group().replaceAll("\'", ""));
    }
    return found;
}
```

but it fails to catch "\'best'days'to come"

Comment: I am wondering of this is a problem that can be solved with regular expressions. What if you have two blocks of quoted text, or nested blocks?

Comment: I think it can.. using a reluctant quantifier

Comment: I think it can too, but not using a using a reluctant quantifier.

Comment: Ah, that text change makes a difference.

Comment: Well @babybang, if you think you can already solve this yourself, why not try and (in case of a failure) post back with whatever you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<!\\\\)'` means "every `'` with no `\` before it"

Using this we can create something like this `(?<!\\\\)'.*?(?<!\\\\)'`

Lets test it

```
    String s="This 'wasn\\'t the best' day. Another 't\\'es\\'t Test' t\\'est";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)'.*?(?<!\\\\)'", "X"));
    //out -> This X day. Test X t\'est
```

Is that you are looking for?

Comment: @babybang This doesn't quite work. It will see `\\'` (`"\\\\'"`) as an escaped quote when really it's an escaped backslash followed by a real quote and should signify the end of the quoted string.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. \ have special meaning for String and for regex so I need to turn it off two times (in two layers): I need to put \\ in regex -> so I need to put \\\\ in String

Comment: @Pshemo I know. See the link in my answer. Your solution will match the entire last line instead of stopping when it sees the `'`.

Answer (score 1):

A regex might look like this:

```
"'([^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*'"
```

As in a single quote `'` followed by 0 to many chacacters that are neither single quotes or is a backslashes, or is a backslash followed by any character, followed by a single quote.

See this [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%27%28%5B%5E%27%5C%5C%5D%7C%5C%5C.%29%2a%27&input=This%20%27wasn%5C%27t%20the%20best%27%20day%0AThis%20%27was%20the%20best%27%20day%0A%27This%20%5C%27whole%5C%27%20line%20%5C%27is%5C%27%20a%20match%27%0A%27This%20ending%20quote%20is%20not%20escaped%5C%5C%27.%20It%20just%20comes%20after%20an%20escaped%20backslash%27)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!\\\\)'([^'\\\\]|\\\\.)*'
```

Using negative lookbehind to ensure the starting quote isn't escaped